# How do you press two keys at the same time with Python Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Trying to do accessibility automation and want to use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to go back an element. But can't seem to get anything to work. 
Tried what the [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.key_down) imply should work based off their "Example, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:":

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
action.key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
action.perform();
```

Then I guessed at :

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.TAB)
action.key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.TAB)
action.perform();
```

And:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT)
action.key_down(Keys.TAB)
action.perform();
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
action.key_up(Keys.TAB)
action.perform();
```

And:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.SHIFT).perform();
```

And:

```
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform() # Tabs 1 forward
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.TAB).perform() # Tabs 1 backwards
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.TAB).perform() # Tabs 1 forward
time.sleep(1)
```

But none of them work. At least at selenium 3.14 & chrome 71.

---

So how do I hit <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> at the same time in Python Webdriver?

**UPDATE**: The correct answer, answered the summary question of two keys at the same time. But my specific example, I had tried the correct way to send them but it was working intermittently. This is because unbeknownst to me it was treating the <kbd>shift</kbd> key as a press down and not release. So the second time I would try it, it was release <kbd>shift</kbd> (and thus not tab backwards every other time). So specially for <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> you need to do this to press, shift, tab, then release shift.

```
# At time of writing this didn't work, but now seems to.
action = ActionChains(context.driver)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT)
action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
action.key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
action.perform()

# Chrome was only taking this at time of writing question.
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.TAB, Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [signature for *send_keys*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys):

```
send_keys(*keys_to_send)
```

The asterisk means it expects a variable number of arguments.
So, you should do something like:

```
send_keys(Keys.ALT, Keys.TAB)
```

Or maybe a combination of *key_down* and *key_up*.

Comment: So this kinda worked but not for the purposes I need. In the interest of keeping the code formatted I added it as the last example to my question. But sending them comma separated goes back 1 element but then if you do it a 2nd time it only goes forward instead.

Comment: Of I get it, for shift you have to send it again to release. Will you please update your answer to include for shift tab the release.
`ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.TAB, Keys.SHIFT).perform()`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get this to work on my end either. Digging around, I found [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088589/selenium-wont-open-a-new-url-in-a-new-tab-python-chrome) that points to [this Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=903), which says:

> This is a limitation in the way we simulate keyboard input in ChromeDriver. Keys get sent directly to the render process, bypassing the browser process. So any keyboard shortcut handlers in the browser process will not be invoked by sendKeys().

Possibly this problem also applies to `ActionChains`. Please let us know if you do figure out a way!

Comment: Just so you know I did get this to work for tabbing to elements. But my solution does not work for opening a new tab as mentioned in this bug.